# Getting AccessDenied when trying to issue a Lamba function, but why?

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda

I've created an AWS Lambda function which is supposed to copy InstanceDBSnapshots from one region to another.

The following policies are attached to the role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1510479591000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:CreateDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:CreateDBSnapshot",
                "rds:CreateDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:DeleteDBInstance",
                "rds:DeleteDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:DeleteDBSnapshot",
                "rds:DeleteDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeDBSecurityGroups",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshotAttributes",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
                "rds:DescribeDBSubnetGroups",
                "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
                "rds:ModifyDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And an Amazon policy called: "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole".

When I run the function I get the following error:

> START RequestId: c5f62f26-c7b6-11e7-8fd4-c9b54c37d712 Version: $LATEST
>   An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeDBSnapshots
>   operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT:assumed-role/cc/Cross-Copy-DB-Snapshots is not
>   authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBSnapshots: ClientError

I don't understand what is that "arn:aws:sts" and how to allow this function to run properly.

Anyone knows this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Should `"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*"
            ]` actually be `"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds::*"
            ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your role; this should work:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
            "rds:DeleteDBSnapshot",
            "rds:CopyDBSnapshot"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```